# 'AdditionalDeploymentContributors' is not a valid argument for the 'Publish' action

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, deployment, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have a set of views of which only 1 needs to be deployed, a different one in each deployment. [Filtering DacPac deployments](https://the.agilesql.club/Blogs/Ed-Elliott/HOWTO-Filter-Dacpac-Deployments) should do it. I'm aware the out of the box options [have improved](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2015/02/23/new-advanced-publish-options-to-specify-object-types-to-exclude-or-not-drop/), but that won't do for my needs.

The database is published through [SqlPackage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx) it explicitly lists these parameters as valid for the publish action. Yet when I use these, it produces the errors (in red):

```
*** 'AdditionalDeploymentContributors' is not a valid argument for the 'Publish' action.
*** 'AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments' is not a valid argument for the 'Publish' action.
```

I use the following command in a Deploy.ps1 file:

```
& $sqlpackageFileName /a:Publish /sf:$DacPacFileName /tcs:$ConnectionString /v:RefToOtherDatabase="${OtherDatabaseName}" /pr:$OptionsFromPublishFile /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributors="AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor" /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments=$NordicsDeployFilter
```

It may be that I'm already getting options from my publishing profile. But if I put them in my PropertyGroup, publishing produces the error: `Contributor initialization error`. Can't get any more details.

1. Why can't it load the AdditionalDeploymentContributor

Edit:
Thanks for your reply, just to keep the question complete, adding what's in my comment.

I'm using SQL Server 2012, which I think is version 110. In my folder structure: `Microsoft SQL Server/110/DAC/bin` I cannot find the .dll you refer to. It is in `Microsoft SQL Server/120/DAC/bin` and I don't have a never version installed so `Microsoft SQL Server/130/DAC/bin` contains very little, no DAC folder.

2. Where should I be adding these .dlls?

When I try to change the config file it produces the error `Please check if this file is opened in another program.`. I've tried stopping SQL Server windows services, thought they might have it in use. Process Explorer can't find the file as in use and Openfiles can't find any open files. Even though I have the file open in Notepad++, so I'm unclear on what that does then.

3. What must I do to edit the config file?

Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2012. With SSDT tools for Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're getting that Contributor initialization error because you're using Ed's contributor with the latest version of SqlPackage.exe.  The deployment contributor was built targeting an earlier version of the DACFx API and we've updated some version numbers.  You can work around this by adding a binding redirect to the SqlPackage.exe.config file.  Here are instructions from Jack Yang on the MSDN SSDT forum (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ee3f886e-6b5e-4b95-b912-e06354534bf9/sqlpackageexe-version-130-wont-load-additionaldeploymentcontributors?forum=ssdt)

> To run against version 130, please modify the SqlPackage.exe.config to add the binding redirect on the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll and Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions.dll. This file can be found right next to SqlPackage.exe.
>
> Example shown in below,
>
> `<runtime>
>       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
>         <dependentAssembly>
>          <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
>           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
>           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="12.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
>         </dependentAssembly>
>         <dependentAssembly>
>           <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
>           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="12.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.100.0.0" />
>         </dependentAssembly>
>         <dependentAssembly>
>           <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
>           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="12.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
>         </dependentAssembly>
>         <dependentAssembly>
>           <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
>           <bindingRedirect oldVersion="12.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
>         </dependentAssembly>
>       </assemblyBinding>
>     </runtime>`
>
> We started shipping AppLocal version of Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom with DacFx in July; therefore, depending on which version of DacFx you have, if you didn’t see the Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll in the same folder with DacFx, then you don’t need the binding redirect for it. It should be in the GAC already.

Comment: I've got a build soon that will use the latest DacFx (nuget) should help this!

Comment: Thanks, Ed. We'll also put these binding redirects in by default in upcoming versions.

Comment: Thanks, but some issue's. 1. I'm using SQL Server 2012, which I think is version 110. In my folder structure: "Microsoft SQL Server/110/DAC/bin" I cannot find the .dll you refer to. It's in the 120 version of the file path that I have, the 130 contains very little, no DAC folder. 2. how do I change this config file? When I try it says "Please check if this file is opened in another program.". I've tried stopping SQL Server windows services.

Comment: I managed to change the config file by renaming the old one, creating a new one and moving it into the folder. I also copied the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Extensions.dll` into the `110/DAC/bin` folder. This made no difference.

Comment: Got it. In that case the recommendation is to install the latest version of SqlPackage.exe (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53013), because it has all of the latest bug fixes. Then follow the steps above to alter the config file in the 130 folder. Note: When installing SqlPackage.exe, be sure to also install the SqlSysClrTypes msi that's linked in a subsection of the download page.

Comment: @StevenGreen Thanks, that loads the deployment contributor. However, during initialization it throws the exception: Could not load file or assembly `Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql` or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
I suspect this is because of different versions and I'm using VS2013, don't have this .dll in my GAC.

Comment: @StevenGreen I'm now using 130 and tried a few things. Didn't think it helped, but now it's gotten further... It now produces the error: An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor

Comment: @StevenGreen And the second part: Error SQL0: Required contributor with id 'AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor' could not be loaded.

Contributor initialization error.
So it still has to do with the deployment contributor.